# Javscript onload in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

i have a requirement to call a javascript method on load of the template.

is there any way to do that in LWC?

Answer (score 24):

Replace an init event handler in an Aura component with the standard JavaScript connectedCallback() method in a Lightning web component.

We use the init event in an Aura component to initialize a component after component construction but before rendering.

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

The doInit function in the component's controller performs any necessary initialization.

```
({
    doInit: function(cmp) {
        // initialize component
    }
})
```

In a Lightning web component, use connectedCallback() instead in the component's JavaScript file.

```
// mySampleInit.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class MySampleInit extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        // initialize component
    }
}
```

Also, read this:- [Run Code When a Component Is Inserted or Removed from the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_lifecycle_hooks_dom.html)

---

if you are intending to use [renderedCallback](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/01/01/renderedcallback-in-lightning-web-component/), You should know that, it will fire after [connectedCallback](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/12/13/connectedcallback-in-lightning-web-component/) and also it may fire more than once(whenever the component rerender itself).

Comment: thank you for the reply, but my requirement is to call the js method when a component is loaded. 

i got the answer like we can use renderedCallback() method to do the job done.

thank you

Comment: Based on [Migrate Initializers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/migrate_initializers) doc

Answer (score 15):

To execute actions when component is rendered, use `renderedCallback()` method and place the required business logic inside this method.

```
// mySampleInit.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class MySampleInit extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        //  the required business logic to be executed when component is rendered
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The upvoted answer from sanket is incorrect IMHO.

Comment: if you are intending to use renderedCallback, You should know that, it will fire after connectedCallback and also it may fire more than once(whenever the component rerender itself).